# monitor nginx with munin

Tags: nginx, munin

I have tried to setup munin to monitor nginx.. I get the graphs in munin but all data is stated as N/A (except the RAM graph which shows used RAM), so I guess there is something wrong with the setup in nginx

But as shown munin is also setup to monitor PHP and it works..

## munin

```
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/nginx_request /etc/munin/plugins/ -v
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/nginx_status /etc/munin/plugins/ -v
cd /var/bin && wget https://github.com/perusio/nginx-munin/archive/master.zip && unzip master.zip
cd nginx-munin-master/ && cp nginx_connection_request nginx_memory /etc/munin/plugins/ -fv
/etc/init.d/munin-node restart
```

## nginx

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        include  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $fastcgi_script_name;
        allow  127.0.0.1;
        deny  all;
    }

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status  on;
        access_log  off;
        allow  127.0.0.1;
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

[image]

## update

```
# munin-run -d nginx_request
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
# Setting /rgid/ruid/ to /117/65534/
# Setting /egid/euid/ to /117 117/65534/
# Setting up environment
# About to run '/etc/munin/plugins/nginx_request'
request.value U
```

Comment: what shows a *munin-run -d nginx_request*

Comment: have updated my question with the output

Comment: okay so clearly there is no output. what's the output of *hostname -f 2>/dev/null | hostname* and *curl -v http://<HOST_FRROM_hostname_call/nginx_status*